# Unix domain socket error, sendmsg: No buffer space available

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, dns

I've got a very simple code snippet, try to know how unix domain socket works, I've written the sender function, not yet having receiver function, it 's like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define ERR_EXIT(m) { \
        perror(m); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    }

void send_fd(int sock_fd, int number){
    iovec vec;
    vec.iov_base = &number;
    vec.iov_len = sizeof(number);

    msghdr msg;
    msg.msg_name = NULL;
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;
    msg.msg_iov = &vec;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    int ret = sendmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
    if (ret != 1)
        ERR_EXIT("sendmsg");
}

int main(void){
    int sockfds[2];
    if (socketpair(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockfds) < 0)
        ERR_EXIT("socketpair");
    send_fd(sockfds[1], 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it on linux, it prints:

```
sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

Well I didn't print this message myself, guess it's printed by sendmsg itself. Where does my program get wrong? I've googled for sometime and check this site, didn't find good clue.

### How to fix it? Thanks.

Yes, should add 
msghrd msg={0}; to initialize, problem solved!

Comment: The output is indeed printed by your code, from the `ERR_EXIT` macro and its use of `perror`.

Comment: Why are you comparing the return value to 1? It can be anything other than `-1` to not have a valid `errno` set.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the code needs to be compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Why?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Probably because the structure variables are defined without the `struct` keyword.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You should probably also write up an answer about that comparison, because it's the cause of the problem of the OP (as [`sendmsg`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendmsg.html) returns the number of *bytes* sent, not the number of messages).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is not. See my answer.

Comment: [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/x1descriptors.htm) contains an example of how to use: `sendmsg()` and `socketpair()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a memset after the msghdr initialization:

```
msghdr msg;
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
```

The problem is that local variables in C (and C++, unless they have constructors) are not initialized. You only initialized some of the fields, but not all of them. The result is that some others (I suspect `msg_control`) had junk in them, causing the error you witnessed.

In addition to that problem, what other people have said in the comments is also true. The code for error is -1 (or, better, `<0`).

Comment: Comparing using `< 0` is working, but [`sendmsg`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendmsg.html) is specified to return `-1` on error (as are most other POSIX system calls), so it's not really "better".

Comment: Can we agree it is a matter of taste?